# React/Redux nested state issue

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, immutable.js

I am new to React/Redux and I am trying to store one of my objects in Redux state as a Map/Hash with the keys being the primary keys from the objects from the db and the values being the object itself.

However the state seems to get overidden each time I am updating and the new value I am adding is the only one that remains. Here is my code:

```
import { RECEIVE_CURRENT_SCAN_RESULT } from '../constants';

const initialState = {
    currentScanResult: {info:{}, results:[]},
};

export default createReducer(initialState, {
    [RECEIVE_CURRENT_SCAN_RESULT]: (state, payload) =>
        Object.assign({}, state, {
            currentScanResult: payload
        })

});


export function createReducer(initialState, reducerMap) {
    return (state = initialState, action) => {
        const reducer = reducerMap[action.type];

        return reducer
            ? reducer(state, action.payload)
            : state;
    }
}
```

I would like to just pass in my object:

```
{id: 1, thing: "blue"}
```

and have the state be updated with it. Then if I pass in:

```
 {id: 2, thing: "red"}
```

I would like my redux state to reflect:

```
currentScanResult: {1: {id: 1, thing: "blue"}, 2: {id: 2, thing: "red"}}
```

Is there any easy way for me to do this? Will redux re-render if I am updating a nested value? For example if I pass in:

```
{id: 2, thing: "purple"}

 => currentScanResult: {1: {id: 1, thing: "blue"}, 2: {id: 2, thing: "purple"}}
```

I would like to see a behavior like this. I've looked into Immutable JS I am just wondering if I can make this simple use case work without it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
Object.assign({}, state, {
    currentScanResult: payload
})
```

you are overriding `state.currentScanResult`. If you want to update it, you need to do something like

```
Object.assign({}, state, {
    currentScanResult: Object.assign({}, state.currentScanResult, payload)
})
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you know if state will update properly with redux nesting it like this? any downsides?

Comment: There is no problem. The more nested the data is the more tedious it becomes to update internal structures. See these docs for more details: http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html

Comment: is this mutating state, for some reason my component isn't re-rendering when the nested values are updated...

Comment: You can try to deep copy the state object in the reducer to make sure a change is detected. Lodash has such a helper function. If it is still not re-rendering then you have a bug elsewhere. If a deep copy helps, consider the link in the comment above - or immutable.js.

Comment: @JulienD  You are still mutating the state (or a property in state) in your answer with `Object.assign(state.currentScanResult, payload)`  because the first argument  of `Object.assign`  is the target that will be modified. So the empty object needs to be the first argument in that line too:  `Object.assign({}, state.currentScanResult, payload)` .